# Docker push to private registry from other server

Tags: docker, repository, registry

Please, I have a problem pushing docker image to a private repository.

Repository: IP 192.168.1.40
Docker Machine 1: 192.168.1.41
Docker Machine 2: 192.168.1.42

When I do the server where I have a docker repository (40):

```
docker pull busybox
docker tag bussybox 192.168.1.40:5000/busybox
docker push 192.168.1.40:5000/busybox
```

So it is between images:
busybox
192.168.1.40:5000/busybox

When I enter the machine (.41)
docker pull 192.168.1.40:5000/busybox
it will download me from server 40
The same on server 42. (download from 40)

But if I want to do it the opposite, it does not work.
When I delete the imgs on machine 40 and run only docker registry and
on machine 41 I will enter:

```
docker pull busybox
docker tag busybox 192.168.1.40:5000/busybox
docker push 192.168.1.40:5000/busybox
```

It does not send it, but it saves it on the current server (41).

**Server 41**

busybox
192.168.1.40:5000/busybox

**Server40**

only registry images

How do I fix it?

I need to create img (pull, build Dockerfile) on server 41 and send (docker push 192.168.1.40:5000/name) to the repository (40). Then I want to download this img (saved on 40) to other servers (42,43,44 .... docker pull)

Comment: it doesnt work means what? paste the errors

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan
On 40
`docker images:
registry`

On 41 (pull, tag, push)
`docker images` is empty
`docker pull busybox
docker tag busybox 192.168.1.40:5000/busybox`

`docker images:
busybox
192.168.1.40:5000/busybox`

`docker push 192.168.1.40:5000/busybox
The push refers to repository [192.168.1.40:5000/busybox]
8a788232037e: Layer already exists
latest: digest: sha256:915f390a8912e16d4beb8689720a17348f3f6d1a7b659697df850ab625ea29d5 size: 527`

On 40 (after push)
`docker images:
registry`

Comment: please paste the logs in the question

Comment: which log?
docker logs containerid - i dont run container
journalctl -fu docker.service - no new data, only old errors

Comment: the above log that u have pasted in commnet , its not readble

Answer (score 0):

Ssh on the other machines(41,42,43,44) and use:
`docker pull 192.168.1.40:5000/busybox`
to pull the image from the registrie host(40).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but "docker pull" from servers 41,42,43 .. works.
But does not work "docker push" from 41 to 40. And when it's not pushing to 40, I can not pull 192.168.1.40:5000/busybox on servers 42,43, ...

I need building apps on 41 (with git) and pushing to repository on 40. 

How meaning is the docker repository if I can not send images there?